# Problem submitting request to node, retry with new node: BUSY

Tags: hedera-hashgraph, hashgraph

I am calling a function from a smart contract:

```
ContractCallQuery query = new ContractCallQuery()
                    .setContractId(ContractId.fromString(request.getContractID()))
                    .setGas(100_000_000)
                    .setFunction(request.getContractFunctionName(), contractFunctionParameters);
```

Which results in a BUSY response (timing out at attempt 47):

```
web - 2023-01-30 22:53:28,795 [Test worker] WARN  c.h.h.sdk.Query$QueryCostQuery - Problem submitting request to node 0.0.3 for attempt #43, retry with new node: BUSY
web - 2023-01-30 22:53:28,936 [Test worker] WARN  c.h.h.sdk.Query$QueryCostQuery - Retrying node 0.0.6 in 8000 ms after failure during attempt #44: BUSY
web - 2023-01-30 22:53:37,032 [Test worker] WARN  c.h.h.sdk.Query$QueryCostQuery - Problem submitting request to node 0.0.5 for attempt #45, retry with new node: BUSY
web - 2023-01-30 22:53:37,182 [Test worker] WARN  c.h.h.sdk.Query$QueryCostQuery - Problem submitting request to node 0.0.3 for attempt #46, retry with new node: BUSY
web - 2023-01-30 22:53:37,321 [Test worker] WARN  c.h.h.sdk.Query$QueryCostQuery - Retrying node 0.0.6 in 8000 ms after failure during attempt #47: BUSY
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
```

This used to work and I havent chaged any code. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `BUSY` error happens when the network gets congested with other users and the throttle has [reached its limit](https://docs.hedera.com/hedera/networks/mainnet#:%7E:text=Transaction%20Throttles). You'll have to wait until the network is no longer congested to complete any transactions.

If you are on testnet consider running a local instance to continue testing. Its highly encouraged to use a local node for development.

Here is a tutorial on how to set up your own local node. https://hedera.com/blog/how-to-set-up-your-own-hedera-local-network-using-docker